# Best way to read xml files without privileges

Tags: c#, xml, sandbox

So I have a string of XML data that I would like read and pull data from in my project, however, it is running in a sort of sandbox mode that blocks the use of system.xml. What are my best options for reading this data?

Since it would only be a basic XML file I thought about just using stringreader and pulling data from it that way using basic string functions, however, this seems a bit far-fetched and I ran into problems finding duplicated closing nodes.

Comment: Is the data always in the same format? If you can put various restrictions on what you need to support then writing a simple XML parser probably isn't that difficult.

Comment: The data should for the most part be in the same format, however one problem I thought of is, there might sometimes be a nested node e.g. <data><data id=1>something</data></data> which would be annoying to find the correct closing tag!